# Compiling gcc-4.1

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, debian

Unfortunately I'm forced to use gcc-4.1 and I'm using debian wheezy. Since gcc-4.1 is not in repository I'm trying to build gcc from sources.

But I'm getting compiling error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

It looks that `ld` is picking wrong version of libraries, but I checked my `/usr/lib32` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and it contains those files:

```
/usr/lib32/libc.a
/usr/lib32/libc.so
/usr/lib32/crtn.o
/usr/lib32/crti.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
```

And `ld` should have access to them

```
~$ echo $LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib32/
```

So I have no idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to work around the problem.

Run configure with:

```
./configure --disable-multilib ...
```

But than I encountered another problem with `makeinfo`, if you have newer version `>=4.10` than it might not be found by configure. So simple fix in generated makefile worked for me:

Change this line:

```
MAKEINFO = /home/lecopivo/Downloads/gcc412/gcc412/gcc-4.1.2/missing makeinfo
```

To this:

```
MAKEINFO = makeinfo
```

I found [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.help/35651) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is only for running programs already linked.

You probably need to set `LDFLAGS` when you configure gcc:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib32" .....
```

It might be `LDFLAGS_FOR_HOST` or `LIBS` or something like that though.

Comment: Thanks but the `./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib32"` didn't help, I tried to fix makefile manually but failed too. Adding `./configure --disable-multilib ...` worked for me.

Comment: The real problem is probably that your old GCC does not have the "multiarch" support needed for Debian/Ubuntu builds (multiarch is not to be confused with multilib). Last I heard, even the latest GCC didn't have that out-of-the-box, but that was a little while ago now. Basically, Debian/Ubuntu put their files in non-standard places, and the compiler can't find them.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem recently and finally solved it this way:

`ln -s /usr/lib32 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

Notes:

1. I assumed you do not have `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` directory in your 64bit linux. If this directory exists and is empty, please delete it and make the above link.
2. If the directory already exists and is not empty, you have to make links inside it for (32bit) libraries which cause build error one by one; e.g.:
   `ln -s /usr/lib32/crti.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o`
   `ln -s /usr/lib32/crtn.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o`
   `...`
3. If 32bit development libraries are not installed, you may have to install them first. I've searched different forums and found that installing following set of packages in ubuntu will provide them:

`libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386`
`gcc-multilib g++-multilib`
`zlib1g-dev lib32z1-dev`
`libncurses5-dev lib32ncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev lib32ncursesw5-dev`

4. Also adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` variables so that they contain `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (i.e. multiarch lib-dirs). I am not sure which one of above variables is effective, so I adjust both of them the same.
5. If you use `./configure --disable-multilib` as it is frequently suggested on web, though gcc will be built, but when you want to use that gcc for compiling e.g. legacy grub, you probably get error of "gcc cannot build executable" (or such).
6. Optionally, you can make similar linking for these pair of libdirs:
   `ln -s /lib32 /lib/i386-linux-gnu`

Doing so, I managed to compile gcc-3.4.6 in a Ubuntu 16.04.6-amd64 used for compiling old 32bit programs like SDL 1.2 and legacy GRUB4DOS 0.4.4.

Also take a look at my answer to similar (though opposite) error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68853169/homebrew-linking-fails-with-incompatible-i386-files-already-on-machine/71626947#71626947).

Good luck.

Comment: This is the solution for original problem, usable for who searches in google, etc about similar problem.