# Homebrew linking fails with incompatible i386 files already on machine

Tags: gcc, homebrew, i386, linuxbrew

I'm hitting this error with anything I have tried to install.

The machine is running redhat and devops has installed newer versions of programs/components in non-standard locations.  I only have user level access.
I have forced homebrew to use non-standard locations of curl and git, but I do not know how to point to a newer version of gcc or tell it to add options to the linker to handle the older (glibc?) files.

```
ld: i386 architecture of input file '/lib/crti.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
ld: i386 architecture of input file '/lib/crtn.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

First adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` variables so that multiarch lib-dirs take lead of other ones. For example, `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` stands before `/usr/lib64` and `/lib`. Now, make this link:
`ln -s /lib64 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

The above linking assumes you do not have `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory. If you have that directory but it is empty, please first remove it then make link. If that directory is not empty, make individual library linking:

`ln -s /lib64/crti.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o`
`ln -s /lib64/crtn.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o`

Overall, to overcome this type of error, the compiler should find correct library (regarding 32bit or 64bit architecture) and necessarily in *multiarch* lib-dirs, which are:

`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
`/lib/i386-linux-gnu`
`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Also take a look at my answer to similar (though opposite) error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443298/compiling-gcc-4-1/71626251#71626251).